# Force local akka serialization

Tags: serialization, akka, actor, akka-remote-actor, remote-actors

I have some doubts regarding akka remote and serialization (what I can and can't do) and for this reason I want to force akka to use remote in the local actor systems.

How can I acheive that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [turn on serialization](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.3.12/scala/serialization.html#Verification) for all messages (remote and local):

```
akka {
  actor {
    serialize-messages = on
  }
}
```